# How can i run tasks based on if a pull request is opened using Azure Devops and yaml?

Tags: azure-devops

I need to run some tasks if a pull request is opened. Im new to this so apologies .

eg A pull request is rasied on github.
If this happens I want to build some review apps based on whether the above condition is true
I need to do this using YAML

Comment: check this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 1):

This is how `pr` trigger works. The below example defines two triggers. When a new pr is created for the **develop** branch then the pipeline will be triggered. This means that pr is open for `develop` branch until it merges. The second trigger will be for main branch. This means that when you merge or commit code on your main branch then the pipeline will be also triggered.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - 'main'    
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

Comment: Thats very useful, I also need to pass a variable to a YAML task with the PR number as is it will be used to create a review app in a resource group in azure. The resource group will be named with the PR number . Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use the predefined variable `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` to get that information. You can then use it accordingly in your pipeline  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: the PR is coming from github so would need the github PR number, will this still work for that?

Comment: @itye1970 yes it will work

Comment: ok i used the code as below but get an error.   "The term 'System.PullRequest.PullRequestId' is not recognized"
steps:
  - bash: echo This script could use $System.PullRequest.PullRequestId
    env:
      System.PullRequest.PullRequestId: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
  - powershell: | 
      Write-Host "This is a script that could use $env:System.PullRequest.PullRequestId"
      Write-Host "$env:System.PullRequest.PullRequestId = $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"
    env:
      System.PullRequest.PullRequestId: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId))

Comment: did you use it with predefined variables syntax? `$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)`

Comment: im using in in yaml file as below     steps:
  # Get PR Request Number
  - powershell: | 
      Write-Host "PR ID is:-" $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

## Starter pipeline

## Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.

## Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:

## https://aka.ms/yaml

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*' 
    
#trigger:
#- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      Write-Host "pullrequest"
      **Write-Host "PR Number is:-" $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"
      Write-Host "PR Number is:-" $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)"**
```